# Are there other ways to read your mail in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm currently on the missions prior to The Big Heist where you have to colect the sports cars. But for some reason my in-game phone is bugged: if I try to read my mail the phone turns to the side a bit and does nothing. Meanwhile I cannot do anything but walk around at normal speed or get out of a vehicle if I am in one. The only way to put the phone away is to either jump out of my vehicle, step in front of another vehicle, walk into deep water or do something else that either ragdolls me or puts me in a position where I can't walk like normal. I have had this bug since a week or so: the first mission I noticed this after was the first Epsilon mission.

Is there another way to access my mail? I'd rather not reinstall the game and download all patches or do something that wipes all my mail.

Comment: I got this bug once with Michael last week - but never before then. Could be something from the most recent update?

Comment: Perhaps. I got it IIRC last monday, when I updated to the most recent version of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated to version 1.23, after which this problem was fixed. I can now read all messages again on all characters.